# "Do you want want to allow this website to open an app on your computer" pop up in internet explorer 10

Tags: javascript, jsp, internet-explorer

I don't know why is this pop-up occuring when i trying to open a JSP url using windows.open(url) in javascript.

Can anyone give an idea how to prevent this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just for security reasons so that a website does not do this:

```
window.open("https://bad_website.com")
```

As far as i know, you cant prevent it, because of security reasons

Comment: Thanks for your reply , although i was able to solve the problem. In my case it was href attribute in anchor tag that was creating problem.

Comment: Nice! Trying to up my reputation. Could you please mark this as the answer?